# Can I write Gurobi log file in csv form?

Tags: python, csv, gurobi, logfile, branch-and-bound

I am wondering if I can have my Gurobi log file in different formats other than txt file.

For instance, is there a Gurobi feature/module/code/whatever that I can change the branch-and-cut tree search section of the log (example shown below) into csv. I am using Python.

```
  Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0 67447.9517    0   52          - 67447.9517      -     -    0s
     0     0 67447.9517    0   35          - 67447.9517      -     -    1s
     0     2 67447.9517    0   35          - 67447.9517      -     -    2s
   349   175 1205.47159   43   25          - 1249.83513      -   173    5s
  1068   744 1245.27358   28  412          - 1249.83513      -   107   10s
H 1068   706                     314.5225665 1249.83513   297%   107   12s
  1078   713 1249.83513   31  399  314.52257 1249.83513   297%   113   15s
* 1677   824             149     890.1137129 1249.83513  40.4%  90.8   17s
* 1725   750             149     890.1320295 1249.83513  40.4%  89.7   17s
* 1726   715             149     890.3483050 1249.83513  40.4%  89.6   17s
  2408  1074  890.48162  122   21  890.34831 1249.83513  40.4%  74.9   20s
H 2502  1014                     891.0039472 1249.83513  40.3%  73.4   20s
H 2884  1186                     899.9697013 1249.83513  38.9%  67.4   22s
H 3370  1478                     904.1957519 1249.83513  38.2%  62.3   23s
  3723  1700  993.88351   70  324  904.19575 1249.83513  38.2%  59.9   25s
  5687  3339  934.17942   99   89  904.19575 1249.83513  38.2%  49.9   30s
  7952  5079  985.43993   72  182  904.19575 1249.83513  38.2%  44.8   35s
```

Should I play around with the text file (read and extract data?). If so, is there a clever way to do it?

Comment: you could import the data into a `pandas dataframe` and from there write `to_csv`... pandas is quite powerful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated Python module to do precisely that: https://github.com/Gurobi/grblogtools

It can read (multiple) log files and stores all the available information in a pandas Dataframe that you can then write out in CSV format if necessary. The package also includes some interactive plotting functionality to visualize the data right away.

example usage:

```
import grblogtools as glt

results = glt.parse(["run1/*.log", "run2/*.log"])
summary = results.summary()
nodelog_progress = results.progress("nodelog")
```